# how can use dynamic array in delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic, insert, frame

i use dynamic array in delphi.

var

```
var
  frame3:array[0..10] of TFrame3
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(sender:TObject);
begin
    frame3[count] := TFrame3.create(self);
    gridpanel2.insertcontrol(frame3[count]);
```

but this code is  'A component named Frame3 alredy exists.'
this error what can ido?

Comment: That's not a dynamic array. I think the key to this though can be found in TFrame3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need multible instances of TFrame3 you need to give it a new name after you created it.

so change

```
 frame3[count] := TFrame3.create(self);
 gridpanel2.insertcontrol(frame3[count]);
```

To

```
 frame3[count] := TFrame3.create(self);
 frame3[count].Name := 'Frame3_' + InttoStr(Count);
 gridpanel2.insertcontrol(frame3[count]);
```

Comment: or just remove name at all

Answer (score 1):

The other issue is that it is not seen in your code how you are changing `count` loop variable. Is it defined in advance?

You need to do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(sender:TObject);
var count:byte;
begin
  for count:=1 to 10 do
    begin
      frame3[count] := TFrame3.create(self);
      ...
    end;
```

or use any other way to set `count` before each array member (class instance) creation. This code will even probably not require to set `Name` property at all.

Comment: The name is set by default, so you have to rename each frame instance